# How can I get the sender pid while receving the SIGSTOP?

Tags: c, linux, signals

As we know, SIGSTOP can't be handled, but my app is always stopped by it.
I receive this report(about my app stopped by SIGSTOP) by using WIFSTOPED/WSTOPSIG functions in my monitor process.

So, how can I do this job?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  The system logs might give you a clue, but you're probably going to have to dial them to max to identify what your looking for. This is not the kind of question that is best asked here at SO.  Perhaps one of the sites that focuses more on Linux system administration?

Answer (score 0):

using  audit !!

centos6:
adding line to /etc/audit/audit.rules(19 is the signal no. i need):

## -a entry,always -F arch=b64 -S kill -k teste_kill -F a1=19

then

## service auditd restart

finally, show log by this:

## ausearch -k teste_kill